# Can we change the trajectory of a body in space using external means?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, space

Suppose a block of metal is floating around in space....can we change its trajectory by external fields?Is it possible if yes then by what type of waves?

Comment: A magnet perhaps?

Comment: suppose the body is small like 5 cm in diameter travelling at 20k mph,will magnetic field change the trajectory? @ZeroTheHero

Answer (score 1):

For example, by [radiation pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure) or by heating a spot on the body by a laser and using the resulting evaporation of metal.

Answer (score 1):

As akhmeteli has stated, radiation pressure will accelerate objects.This is the basis of proposed solar sails to accelerate probes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail , Also the Pioneer space probes were pushed very slowly off course from radiated thermal energy. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_BxS_TErYQ&t=227s